# SaveImage of ChartControl without display It in the screen

Tags: c#, image, controls, microsoft-chart-controls

I wanna save a ChartControl to an Image without display it in the screen.

```
var theChart = new Chart();
var theSeries = new Series("values");
theSeries.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
theChart.Series.Add(theSeries);
theSeries.Points.AddXY(1, 1);
theSeries.Points.AddXY(2, 2);
theSeries.Points.AddXY(3, 3);
theChart.SaveImage(@"D:\Téléchargements\HiddenChart4.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

Then I get a blank picture. I think it's because the control is not paint. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the answer with the missing part

```
var theChart = new Chart();

        //missing part
        var chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
        theChart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);

        var theSeries = new Series("values");
        theSeries.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
        theChart.Series.Add(theSeries);
        theSeries.Points.AddXY(1, 1);
        theSeries.Points.AddXY(2, 2);
        theSeries.Points.AddXY(3, 3);
        theChart.SaveImage(@"D:\Téléchargements\HiddenChart6.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```